# NSStream: Is there any airtight defense against blocking?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, stream

Under the [Stream Programming Guide: Polling versus Run-Loop Scheduling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/PollingVersusRunloop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002275-CJBEDDBG) section, the last para says:

> It should be pointed out that neither the polling nor run-loop
>   scheduling approaches are airtight defenses against blocking. If the
>   NSInputStream `hasBytesAvailable` method or the NSOutputStream
>   `hasSpaceAvailable` method returns NO, it means in both cases that the
>   stream definitely has no available bytes or space. However, if either
>   of these methods returns YES, it can mean that there is available
>   bytes or space or that the only way to find out is to attempt a read
>   or a write operation (which could lead to a momentary block). The
>   `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` and `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`
>   stream events have identical semantics.

So, it seems neither `hasBytesAvailable`/`hasSpaceAvailable`, nor stream events provide a guarantee against blocking. Is there any way to get guaranteed non-blocking behaviour with streams? I could create a background thread to get guaranteed non blocking behaviour, but I want to avoid doing that.

Also, I fail to understand why `NSStream` can't provide gauranteed non-blocking behaviour given that the low-level APIs (select, kqueue, etc.) can do so. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

You either run your reading or writing in a different thread or you can't use NSStream. There are no other ways to get guaranteed non-blocking behavior.

For regular files and sockets you most likely will get non-blocking behavior if you schedule the stream on a runloop. But there are other types of stream that are not implemented on top of a file descriptor. By documenting the base class as not always non-blocking Apple keeps options open of implementing different streams in a way where they can't guarantee the non-blocking property.

But since we can't check the source code we can only speculate on this. You might want to file a bug with Apple requesting them to update the docs with that information.

Comment: What other type of stream does Apple provide where they won't be able to guarantee non-blocking behaviour? Besides files and sockets, I can only think of in-memory streams, but these won't block.

Comment: Right now I can only think of socket streams using SSL.

Comment: Yes SSL streams is another one, though it should not be impossible to provide non-blocking behaviour for SSL/TLS either. OpenSSL APIs, for example, do allow one to write [fully](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html) [non](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_read.html)-[blocking](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_write.html) [code](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_pending.html). That said, perhaps Apple's SSL implementation isn't as flexible as OpenSSL's.